# Can I set Structured Message (JSON) to send msg before start chatbot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-ads-api, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to set structured Message (JSON) from ads manager to send the message in messengers which has chatbot in page after users clicks ads ?

Step from user exp.

1. User sees ads from FB timeline.
2. User click ads
3. redirected to FB Page
4. User see a message in messenger with "Get started" button to activated FB chatbot.
5. User click "Get started" button to talk to bot.

ref : https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1646890868956360

Comment: I doubt it … In the scenario that you’re describing, I don’t see an actual connection between the ad, and the user eventually landing inside the messenger - since the ad directed them to the page only, and after that they are free to do whatever they like there - either use messenger, or not. Only with an actual Click-to-Messenger ad I could see that making sense; and even then you would only get the ad id, and only after the user started an actual conversation. Your bot’s _reply_ to that could then change based on the ad id, but that won’t be configured inside the ad itself either.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I mean Is it possible to set starter message after user click on ads (ads will direct to page and that page has chatbot)?  From what I know is we can set structured message from ads manager to page that hasn't chatbot.

Comment: Click-to-Messenger ads will let the user go from ad->bot but there is now way to go from ad->page->send message from bot